# Each time the C code exits after reading the certain number of files

Tags: c, fopen

I have two sets of data files "P" (position) and "F" (force) files. Separately (in two different codes) the codes can open and read all "P" and "F" files. When I try to read them together in single code, the code opens and reads data from files, but only 1004 of "P" file and then exits.  I cannot even debug it as it shows a normal exit.
What should I do to debug the code? The computer has enough memory and the data files are not large. Here is part of the code which opens the files:

```
...
FILE *finput1, *finput2;
char  filename[160], filename2[160];
...
for (i=0;i<N_f1;i++) {
sprintf(filename, "F%d.dat", i);
    finput1=fopen(filename,"r");
if( finput1 == NULL ) {
    printf(" Could not open F file!\n");
    return 0;
}

sprintf(filename2, "P%d.dat", i);
finput2=fopen(filename2,"r");
if( finput2 == NULL ) {
    printf(" Could not open P file! %d \n",i);
    return 0;
}
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running into a maximum number of file descriptors. Close each file after you open the next one.

Comment: thank you. I have changed the code and after reading each file, I close it and it works! Thank you

Comment: Sorry guys, I do not have enough reputation to vote up your replies.

Answer (score 2):

The files that can be open simultaneously is limited, you can check the value of `FOPEN_MAX` in `stdio.h`.

Note that it is the minimum number of files that the implementation guarantees, you might open more than it in practice.

Comment: Thank you, you are right it was the number of open files.